# Guessing strings non-recursively

Tags: swift, recursion

I am making a Swift program to stress test certain pieces of computer hardware for a research project I am working on. One of the programs I am making is guessing a password. I currently have an implementation that works by doing it recursively.

```
func passwordCracker(_ password: String, _ guess: String) {
        for letter in letters {
            let newGuess = guess + letter
            tryCount = tryCount + 1
            if (password == newGuess) {
                let stop = DispatchTime.now().rawValue
                print("the password is \(newGuess) and it took \((stop - start)/1_000_000_000) seconds and \(tryCount) guesses.")
                //return
                
                //This causes the program to "crash" ending all the other recursive calls.
                //We use this instead of return as return will still continue to do other recursive calls after the fact
                exit(0)
            }
        }
        
        if(guess.count + 1 >= depth) { return }
        
        for letter in letters {
            passwordCracker(password, guess + letter)
        }
    }
```

I want to create a way of doing it non-recursively but have been unable to do so. My current implementation works only when the password to be guessed is in alphabetical order (abc, abcd, etc.). Would welcome any suggestions on how to fix it.

```
func iterative(_ pwd: String) {
        var guess = ""
        for _ in 0..<depth {
            for letter in letters {
                guess = guess + letter
                for l in letters {
                    if guess + l == pwd {
                        print("Password found. It is: \(pwd)")
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print("Password NOT found")
    }
```

Comment: @matt the second function doesn't work [which would make the post off-topic for CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). In the future when voting to close a question please use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc.  instead. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @matt The first version is only there to explain the expected behavior, the second version is the real topic of the question because it doesn't work.  OP explains that what is its wrong behavior. While the malfunction could perhaps have been explained with more elements,  doesn't this meet the minimum requirements for SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues with your versions

The problem with your recursive version is that the limits on [stack size](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) are quickly reached due to its elementary approach and the combinatorial explosion.

The algorithm works with a depth first exploration, and relies on the backtracking the recursive call allows:  once you have reached a dead-end (no more letter to add and string not guessed),  you return,  and the previous level of recursion starts with the next combination restarting from previous guess.

By the way, instead of using `exit` you could make your function returns a boolean that would be true if the right combination is found.  This would allow to gracefully return recursively instead of loosing time to explore all the other possibilities.

In your iterative guessing version, you only have one `guess` and only add letters to it, but if you have reached a dead-end, you do not backtrack (or just by one letter). This is why you explore only a small part of the possibilities.

### How to make an iterative version

If you want to transform a recursive exploration of string combinatorics into an iterative one,  you need to use a queue. Here is how a string guessing function could look like:

```
func iterativeGuess(_ solution: String) {
    var queue  = [ "" ]         // start with an empty string
    for _ in 0..<depth {        // depth first approach
        var newqueue =  [ String ] ()
        for guess in queue {    // add a letter to each strings generated
            for letter in letters {
                let newguess = guess + letter
                if newguess == solution {
                    print("String guessed. It is: \(newguess)")
                    return
                }
                else {
                    newqueue.append(newguess)
                    print ("tried \(newguess)")
                }
            }
        }
        queue = newqueue
    }
    print("String not guessed")
}
```

This function uses a breath-first exploration to guess a known string: first it tries all possible combination of length 1, then all the combinations of length 2 and so on.  I leave as an exercise to transform it in depth first.

***Disclaimer:** It is important to underline that the question and its code appears to be about simulating the time to guess an already known string using brute-force for legitimate purposes and without malicious intent. The answer provided bears no risk of harm; the elementary knowledge provided is available in any CS textbook.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I know the recursive version causes issues with the stack size, but it is intentional as we are exploring the affect of stack displacement on a programs runtime so we wanted a program where we could get large stack sizes if we chose to. And thanks for your iterative version. It is super helpful and should work perfectly.

Comment: Also I believe the exit(0) in my code prevents it from testing out all the other guesses in the other recursive calls.

Comment: @ThomasBraun glad that it helped.  Don't hesitate to upvote if it helped, or to accept the answer if it solves your problem ;-)